# add base64 string as a file in Flask request

Tags: python, file, flask

Variable `photo` contains an image in base64 string format I would like to  create a Flask Request and use this string as a file,

```
fr = Request({})
fr.method = 'POST'
fr.root_path = root_path
fr.path = '/server/'
fr.headers = headers
fr.files = {'photo':photo} # This line needs to be corrected
```

would you please help how to add the string as a file.

Comment: `io.BytesIO(base64.decodebytes(photo.encode()))` ?

Comment: @Kris , Thank you. I had to remove `data:image/jpeg:base64,` from my string and then use your code.